# CRM plugin is registered using "Plugins Registration tool" successfully but it's effect is not visible in Dynamics 365 trial

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365

[We have Created class library in VS 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg594416.aspx) using **Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk**. The full articles check The code is shown below:

```
namespace SamplePlugins
{
public class PostCreateContact : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
           serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        // The InputParameters collection contains all the data
        //passed in the message request.
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            try
            {
                // Create a task activity to follow up with the account customer in 7 days
                Entity followup = new Entity("task");
                followup["subject"] = "Send e-mail to the new customer.";
                followup["description"] = "Follow up with the customer. Check if there are any new issues that need resolution.";
                followup["scheduledstart"] = DateTime.Now;
                followup["scheduledend"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                followup["category"] = context.PrimaryEntityName;
                // Refer to the contact in the task activity.
                if (context.OutputParameters.Contains("id"))
                {
                    Guid regardingobjectid = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
                    string regardingobjectidType = "contact";
                    followup["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference(regardingobjectidType, regardingobjectid);
                }
                // Obtain the organization service reference.
                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                IOrganizationService service =
                   serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
                // Create the followup activity
                service.Create(followup);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

We are creating Plugins using **PluginRegistration.exe** tools as shown below:

[PluginRegistration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RuU8.png)

And Plugin is working correctly but my problem is that, its not displaying in CRM. The image is shown below:

[DYnamic CRM image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTuYU.png)

After registering the plugin successfully, when I try to add a new contact it throws the error as below:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unexpected exception from plug-in
>   (Execute): SamplePlugins.PostCreateContact:
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.Detail:  
>   ea1ed3a5-05b4-42ee-bd89-d02fe825d3b7
>   -2147220956      Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute):
>   SamplePlugins.PostCreateContact: System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.
>   2017-10-31T07:42:32.9360245Z
>   false
>
> [SamplePlugins: SamplePlugins.PostCreateContact]
>   [e326c926-0dbe-e711-a94d-000d3af2242b:
>   SamplePlugins.PostCreateContact: Create of contact]
>   FieldServicePlugin: PluginLocal.Create, Depth: 1 FieldServicePlugin:
>   PluginContext Start FieldServicePlugin: MessageName: Create
>   FieldServicePlugin: PrimaryEntityName: contact FieldServicePlugin:
>   PrimaryEntityId: 8c28820d-0fbe-e711-a94d-000d3af2242b
>   FieldServicePlugin: SecondaryEntityName: none FieldServicePlugin:
>   Stage: 20 FieldServicePlugin: PreEntityImages.Count: 0
>   FieldServicePlugin: PostEntityImages.Count: 0 FieldServicePlugin:
>   InputParameters:      Target = Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity
>   FieldServicePlugin: OutputParameters:  FieldServicePlugin:
>   SharedVariables:      DefaultsAddedFlag = True FieldServicePlugin:
>   UserId: 2a4cb21f-cfec-40fa-9af1-f70eaeee50f8 FieldServicePlugin:
>   InitiatingUserID: 2a4cb21f-cfec-40fa-9af1-f70eaeee50f8
>   FieldServicePlugin: IsolationMode: 1 FieldServicePlugin: Mode: 0
>   FieldServicePlugin: OrganizationName: orgd88c5494 FieldServicePlugin:
>   OrganizationId: 331b6d4f-5185-46f8-b0ed-b12e55a03f99
>   FieldServicePlugin: BusinessUnitId:
>   56c7a0d3-12a6-e711-a94c-000d3af2546a FieldServicePlugin:
>   CorrelationId: e50930dc-9daf-4eb5-9327-f8e7f6358b4b
>   FieldServicePlugin: RequestId: e7e46348-7922-41a5-af2c-30795106831c
>   FieldServicePlugin: OperationId: e7e46348-7922-41a5-af2c-30795106831c
>   FieldServicePlugin: IsInTransaction: True FieldServicePlugin: Depth: 1
>   FieldServicePlugin: IsExecutingOffline: False FieldServicePlugin:
>   Parent PluginContext Start FieldServicePlugin:        PluginContext Start
>   FieldServicePlugin:       MessageName: Create FieldServicePlugin:
>         PrimaryEntityName: contact FieldServicePlugin:      PrimaryEntityId:
>   8c28820d-0fbe-e711-a94d-000d3af2242b FieldServicePlugin:
>         SecondaryEntityName: none FieldServicePlugin:       Stage: 30
>   FieldServicePlugin:       PreEntityImages.Count: 0 FieldServicePlugin:
>         PostEntityImages.Count: 0 FieldServicePlugin:       InputParameters: 
>     Target = Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity   SuppressDuplicateDetection = False
>   FieldServicePlugin:       OutputParameters:  FieldServicePlugin:
>         SharedVariables:    DefaultsAddedFlag = True FieldServicePlugin:
>         UserId: 2a4cb21f-cfec-40fa-9af1-f70eaeee50f8 FieldServicePlugin:
>         InitiatingUserID: 2a4cb21f-cfec-40fa-9af1-f70eaeee50f8
>   FieldServicePlugin:       IsolationMode: 1 FieldServicePlugin:        Mode: 0
>   FieldServicePlugin:       OrganizationName: orgd88c5494
>   FieldServicePlugin:       OrganizationId:
>   331b6d4f-5185-46f8-b0ed-b12e55a03f99 FieldServicePlugin:
>         BusinessUnitId: 56c7a0d3-12a6-e711-a94c-000d3af2546a
>   FieldServicePlugin:       CorrelationId:
>   e50930dc-9daf-4eb5-9327-f8e7f6358b4b FieldServicePlugin:      RequestId:
>   e7e46348-7922-41a5-af2c-30795106831c FieldServicePlugin:
>         OperationId: e7e46348-7922-41a5-af2c-30795106831c
>   FieldServicePlugin:       IsInTransaction: True FieldServicePlugin:
>         Depth: 1 FieldServicePlugin:        IsExecutingOffline: False
>   FieldServicePlugin:       PluginContext End FieldServicePlugin: Parent
>   PluginContext End FieldServicePlugin: PluginContext End
>   FieldServicePlugin: PluginLocal.Create, Depth: 1 FieldServicePlugin:
>   PluginLocal.Create, Depth: 1 FieldServicePlugin: InitializePlugin:
>   local FieldServicePlugin: ConfigurePluginFlagsSupportInternal()
>   FieldServicePlugin: CreateEntityOperation(contact) FieldServicePlugin:
>   Operation type: ContactOperation FieldServicePlugin:
>   operation.Initialize() FieldServicePlugin: InputEntity:   territorycode
>   = 1   address2_freighttermscode = 1   address2_shippingmethodcode = 1     isprivate = False   followemail = True  donotbulkemail = False
>     donotsendmm = False     haschildrencode = 1     educationcode = 1
>     customertypecode = 1    fullname = d p  isautocreate = False    ownerid =
>   2a4cb21f-cfec-40fa-9af1-f70eaeee50f8_systemuser[]
>     isbackofficecustomer = False    donotbulkpostalmail = False
>     donotpostalmail = False     donotemail = False  statecode = 0
>     address2_addresstypecode = 1    donotphone = False  createdon =
>   10/31/2017 7:42:32 AM     transactioncurrencyid =
>   fa08936e-19a6-e711-a94c-000d3af2546a_transactioncurrency[]    contactid
>   = 8c28820d-0fbe-e711-a94d-000d3af2242b    modifiedby = 2a4cb21f-cfec-40fa-9af1-f70eaeee50f8_systemuser[]  leadsourcecode = 1
>     statuscode = 1  modifiedonbehalfby =    preferredcontactmethodcode = 1
>     lastname = p    firstname = d   createdby =
>   2a4cb21f-cfec-40fa-9af1-f70eaeee50f8_systemuser[]     yomifullname = d p
>     donotfax = False    merged = False  customersizecode = 1    marketingonly
>   = False   owningbusinessunit = 56c7a0d3-12a6-e711-a94c-000d3af2546a_businessunit[]
>     shippingmethodcode = 1  creditonhold = False    modifiedon = 10/31/2017
>   7:42:32 AM    participatesinworkflow = False
>     preferredappointmenttimecode = 1 FieldServicePlugin:
>   operation.Execute() FieldServicePlugin: PluginStage: 20 MessageName:
>   Create FieldServicePlugin: Before calling message handler
>   FieldServicePlugin: Before FieldServicePlugin: BeforeCreate
>   FieldServicePlugin: BeforeCreateOrUpdate FieldServicePlugin: Settings:
>   Retrieving local FieldServicePlugin: Settings: Retrieving hard
>   FieldServicePlugin: After calling message handler FieldServicePlugin:
>   PluginLocal.Dispose, Depth: 1 FieldServicePlugin: PluginLocal.Dispose,
>   Depth: 1 FieldServicePlugin: PluginLocal.Dispose, Depth: 1

Comment: FileIOPermisssion error means you're trying to read or write a file on disk from the sandbox, are you sure that's the exact code that produces this error log ?

Comment: It says Fieldservice plugin too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Plugin name is PostCreateAccount & checking `context.OutputParameters.Contains("id")` which means PK of just created Account.

But you are referring it to RegardingObjectId as Contact while creating task. And verifying in CRM contact record. Do an advanced find for tasks created & you can troubleshoot.

For consistency make sure of this - Your step name in PRT says “Update of Account”.

I do see PostCreateContact plugin in your screenshot, if you are playing around with code, verify all the changes you are making.

**Update:**
By seeing your exception, this is coming from FieldService plugin which is installed per your trial subscription. If you are not using, You may remove the FieldService solution Or unregister the Assembly. Or Simply just disable the below Step in PRT.

[image]

Comment: Sorry it's my Mistake , i do similarly for account also but it's same issues.

Comment: Yes, after changes plugin is registered successfully but when I try to add a new contact at that time it is still giving me the error. The message I have updated above.

Comment: See my updated answer. This is going broad in SO. If you have different issue, ask a different question

Comment: I have already attached screenshot of my plugin registration tool with all processes, and there is no such FieldService plugin is there. Let me know if I'm missing something here.